# Deserialize to List and not Dictionary without temporarily creating a dictionary

Tags: c#, json.net

I have JSON data from an API that is like this where Members is feed as a dictionary:

```
{
  "otherdata": "blahblah",
  "members": {
    "500349788": {
      "joined_at": 1535145965,
      "account_id": 500349788
    },
    "500939277": { // key is actually account_id
      "joined_at": 1527791258,
      "account_id": 500939277,
    }
  }
}
```

How do I get this deserialized to these objects where members is a list or collection:

```
class MyData {
  string OtherData;
  List<Member> Members;
}

class Member {
  long JoinedAt;
  long AccountId;
}
```

I can only get it to deserialize to `Dictionary<string, Member>` so I assume I need some sort of converter to make the dictionary become a list where the key is simply discarded.

Current code do the conversion as an extra step today - looking for a more maintainable solution.

Comment: The json structure **is** a dictionary, you will have to temporarily deserialize into a dictionary and then grab the values.

Comment: Yes, as suggested, deserialize to Dicitonary and then call `Members.Values.ToList()`

Comment: Hoping to avoid temporary objects, maybe with a JsonCoverter or something?

Comment: @Fabjan Thats how I am doing it now, and it's a nightmare to maintain. So seeking a better solution.

Comment: It's been a while since I did .NET but as far as I can remember, this should be possible using a custom `JsonConverter` that CanRead a `Member` instance. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using a custom `JsonConverter` implementation. You would need to register it to the serializer settings, or add it as an attribute to the class

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = "... your api response";
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(json, new Converter());
        Console.WriteLine(data);
    }
}

class Converter : JsonConverter<List<Member>>
{
    public override bool CanRead => true;

    public override List<Member> ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, List<Member> existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var result = JToken.Load(reader).ToObject<IDictionary<string, Member>>();
        return result.Values.ToList();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, List<Member> value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        //maybe you also want to convert back
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class MyData
{
    [JsonProperty("otherdata")]
    string OtherData;
    [JsonProperty("members")]
    List<Member> Members;
}

class Member
{
    [JsonProperty("joined_at")]
    long JoinedAt;
    [JsonProperty("account_id")]
    long AccountId;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Was just what I needed. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what type of code maintenance issue you are running into, but to me this would be one way in which you can handle the situation and seems, to me, like a clean way to handle this situation (as I am also assuming there is no way to change the JSON you are getting back).  I will also note that this code is not thread safe, but you could add locking or something like that if needed.

So a workaround would be to modify your `MyData` class to deserialize the dictionary but as a private member and then have a list property which is lazy loaded from the dictionary.  This leaves your `MyData` definition basically intact, allows for the deserializing (albeit into the dictionary), but you just handle the conversion within the data class so it should be pretty easy to maintain.

```
public sealed class MyData
{
    [JsonProperty("otherdata")]
    public string OtherData {get; private set;}

    [JsonProperty("members")]
    private Dictionary<string, Member> _myData;

    private List<Member> _myMembers;
    public IReadOnlyList<Member> Members
    {
        get
        {
            if (_myMembers == null)
            {
                _myMembers = _myData?.Values.ToList() ?? new List<Member>();
                _myData = null; // Optional dumping of the dictionary
            }

            return _myMembers
        }
    }
}
```